# Android - App will not read sharedpreferences from Library correctly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app was working great until I got it ready for deployment. I have a portion of my app that checks to see if a checkmark is checked in the preferences. Well since I added as a library and am running through another application (created a free version of the app and trying to keep my code as a library) it always returns false.

```
        SharedPreferences appPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.company.widget_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean blNotifications;
            blNotifications = appPrefs.getBoolean("notifications_new_message", false);

if (blNotifications)
{
   //always returns false
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you do have that key in there `notifications_new_message`? If it does not exist it defaults to `false` - can you confirm that?

Comment: post your read portion of the code.

Comment: Could be it's not allowed to read it?  You did add the detail it's as a library, could that make it a different package and thus denied access?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I know it worked fine before I made my app a library, now it doesn't. The weird thing is the preferences I set manually work fine, but the preferences set by the preference activity do not. Chillax - That's what I'm not sure about. Don't know if there is a rights thing with it or not. I tried changing all of the preferences to MODE_WORLD_READ, but that has been deprecated in 17. tOmm13b - I did confirm it was there. This happens in two different places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys. For some reason using `SharedPreferences appPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences` worked in dev, but as soon as I made it into a Library it didn't like it anymore. The correct way to call a default sharepreference is the following.

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String value = pref.getString("name_of_my_pref", "default_value");
```

Thanks again.